# videoJs inactivityTimeout option not working

Tags: video.js

I'm trying to set the `inactivityTimeout` on my video element to shorten the time it takes for the control bar to hide. However, the following doesn't seem to change it:

```
const opts = {
    controlBar: {
        volumePanel: {
            inline: false,
            vertical: true
        },
    },
    inactivityTimeout: 100,
};

videojs(myVideoEl, opts);
```

When I do this it does work, but I get a warning:

```
player.options().inactivityTimeout = 500;
```

> VIDEOJS: WARN: this.options() has been deprecated and will be moved to
>   the constructor in 6.0

Does anyone know why I can't seem to set it using the options?

Answer (score 2):

```
var player = videojs("sessionsimple-player",{
    inactivityTimeout: 100,
    controlBar: {
        volumePanel: {
            inline: false,
            vertical: true
        },
    }
});
```

Note: Do not use both data-setup and an options object.
https://docs.videojs.com/tutorial-setup.html#options